# Как объединить массивы? Javascript

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как объединить три многомерных-массива в один массив?

```
var defaultRows = [
  [1,4,7,10,13,16,19],
  [2,5,8,11,14,17,20],
  [3,6,9,12,15,18,21]
];

var temporatyArray = [
  [],
  [],
  []
];
var temporatyArray2 = [
  [],
  [],
  []
];
```

Comment: Подробнее можно? С кодом желательно

Comment: Приведите пример того как выглядят ваши многомерные массивы и что Вы хотите получить в результате.

Comment: Результат: var array = [defaultRows, temporatyArray1, temporatArray2];

Comment: `var array = [defaultRows, temporatyArray1, temporatArray2];` - Это и есть решение вопроса - вполне допустимая запись

Comment: Ну тогда Всем спасибо)))

Comment: @Grundy, мне кажется топикстартер хочет плоский массив из элементов, или spread

Comment: @DenisoDeniso, нажимаете F12 - это - консоль браузера, с помощью которой можно много чего сделать, в том числе посмотреть как работают те или иные простые конструкции

Comment: @DenisoDeniso есть вкладка console, там можно что-нибудь повыполнять в контексте странички на которой Вы консоль открыли

Comment: http://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome, плюс вообще очень рекомендую это учебник

Comment: Я и начал этого учебника заниматься)Подача материала хорошая

Comment: Так собственно к вопросу. Вот у вас есть 3 массива  3x7. Что значит "объединить их в один массив"? Что хотим в результате? Массив 3x3x7? Массив 9x7? Массив 3x21? Массив 1x63? Один массив 3x7?

Comment: Вот это мне нужно было)) : var array = [defaultRows, temporatyArray1, temporatArray2];

Answer (score 3):

```js
var a = [[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]];
var b = [[2,4],[2,4],[2,4]];
var c = [[3,5],[3,5],[3,5]];

var res = a.concat(b, c);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: А в es6 можно var res = [...a, ...b, ...c]; Но тс хотел не этого)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму написано три массива объединить. не написано же вложить три массива в общий. а я что сделал?

Comment: ага, вечная дилема so: отвечать на вопрос который задали или который хотели задать)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму сообщество телепатов ))